# уволен за не формат

Tags: выбор-слов

Мавлютов уволен за «не формат».  В тексте: глава администрации отметил, что МАВЛЮТОВ работал «не в формате». То есть «не формат» пишем раздельно?

Answer (score 5):

Здесь логичнее слитно и без кавычек. Поскольку образуется новое понятие.
А если кто-то пишет иначе, так на них есть хорошая русская пословица про тех, кому закон не писан.

Что же касается второго случая, который в тексте, то там есть предлог, который исключает слитное написание, но тут и отрицание "формата", а не понятие "неформат".

Answer (score 2):

Неформат – от французского (фр. format, от лат. formatus — сформированный)
1) издательский термин, означающий размер книги, газеты, листа, иллюстрации;
2) внутренний термин телевидения и FM-радиостанций, обозначающий любой материал — чаще музыкальный, — неприемлемый для трансляции по соображениям «формата» того или иного СМИ: редакционной политики, определенных стилистических или вкусовых пристрастий слушателей, зрителей, читателей и т. п.
Неформат служит эффективным орудием отбраковки всего, что, как представляется менеджерам вещательной структуры, может сказаться на популярности станции, количестве аудитории и т.д.  («Альтернативная культура. Энциклопедия»).
Слово "формат" сначала имело очень узкое прозаическое значение. Оно предполагало всего лишь определенный метраж передачи, обусловленный сеткой вещания. То есть под форматом подразумевался временной отрезок времени. Затем, поскольку вещание стало более адресным и целевым и вследствие этого дифференцированным и специализированным, то появилось выражение: "Не наш формат". В него вкладываются претензии как чисто технического порядка, так и концептуального свойства.
Но сами слова (термины) ФОРМАТ и НЕФОРМАТ пишутся слитно, а правильное написание  -  В НЕФОРМАТЕ.

Answer (score 0):

Мавлютов уволен за **неформат**.

Запись **Мавлютов уволен за «не формат»** возможна, если рассматривать ее в виде краткого дословного высказывания (цитаты) на данную тему, поэтому словосочетание  заключено в кавычки. Можно, к примеру,  написать: Он уволен за  "использование  материала, неприемлемого в рамках существующего формата".

Из словарей:

**НЕФОРМАТНЫЙ**,  Не соответствующий обычному или нужному формату. Н-ые книги. Н-ые документы. **Неформат**,  (к неформатный).

**Словообразование: форматный ― неформатный ― нефомат.**

В дальнейшем слово "неформат"  расширярло  свое значение. Сначала писали в кавычках в качестве малоизвестного слова (скорее всего мой блог будет воспринят  как некий "**неформат**"), потом кавычки убрали ( **неформат** меня не интересует).